# Is it expensive to create class objects and type vectors?

Tags: c++, performance, object, vector

Is it expensive to create class objects and type vectors? 
What is more expensive? Objects or vectors? why the downvotes?

thanks

```
class player player1;
class player player2; 
class player player3;
std::vector<player> playervec1;
std::vector<player> playervec2;
std::vector<player> playervec3;
```

Comment: Vectors are objects that contain other objects.

Comment: Because this is off-topic:  "too broad. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."  If `player` is a class that computes prime numbers, it's going to be more expensive to instantiate it three times, than three vectors. If `player` is a completely empty class, it's going to be faster to initialize three of them, than three vectors, which have some initialization to do.

Comment: This question feels like a broad attempt at *"What is a vector and how do they work?"*

Comment: Neither is likely to be particularly expensive (the vector's certainly not - you're not even storing anything in them so they're just a few pointers each likely set to 0, though may hold a few extra bits of data in "debug" builds).  Anyway, just ***write the code that does what your program needs to do***, then worry about memory usage and performance *if it proves necessary*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your question is simply that "a class object," and "a vector of *{anything_at_all},"* are two **entirely** different things!

You don't seem to know what you're talking about. **:-/**

In your code-snippet, you first create three `player` objects.

Then, you create three *totally different, and unrelated(!)* things:   three `vector` objects, whose contents just-happen to be `player`s.

And then, you ask about one-or-the-other being "expensive?"    Well, one's an apple, and the other's an orange.

"The error of your ways" is simply that these two operations have no possible bearing on one another.  *And* that, even if they did, the question as-posed has no real meaning.  "It's the language-compiler's *job* to do both of these things as efficiently as possible ... but, having said that, they're absolutely-and-completely unrelated to one another!"